# How to move just one value in a table to a different column

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a command for moving only the value 11 to the right column in the following column?

```
| Name |    |   |
|------+----+---|
| a    | 11 |   |
| b    | 10 |   |
```

Something like `org-table-move-column` but applying to a single cell only.

Comment: There's no out of the box solution that I know of. Have a look at `org-table-copy-down` in *org-table.el* , It will give you the basis to write your function. your

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive function that I put together in few minutes. It uses interactive commands, so there must be a more correct way of doing the same thing.

Org table commands behave in quite surprising ways. See command documentation to understand better what is happening here.

This function does not delete the cell content in the next cell, but prepends to it. It should be easy to modify it to remove the next cell content first.

```
 (defun org-table-prepend-cell-to-right ()
   "Cut table cell content and prepend it to cell contects on its right."
   (interactive)
   (when (org-at-table-p 'any)
     (goto-char (1+ (point)))
     (call-interactively 'org-table-beginning-of-field)
     (let ((start (point)) (string))
       (call-interactively 'org-table-end-of-field)
       (setq string (concat (delete-and-extract-region start (point)) " "))
       (org-table-next-field)
       (insert string)
       (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c))))
```

Comment: This function exits at the call to `org-backward-sentence` with `Wrong type argument: commandp, org-table-beginning-of-field`. Does it work on your computer and which version of Emacs are you using? I'm using 26.1.

Comment: It works for me for almost all cells of a table, It does not take into account all edge cases. It does work if you put the cursor on string "11" in your example. I am using GNU Emacs 26.1, but more importantly, I am using Org mode version 9.1.14.

Comment: I upgraded Org mode to 9.1.14 now. However, running `org-backward-sentence` still exits with the same error. This is strange because it is a basic org-mode command that has existed for some time. Do you have any suggestions on how to debug this? Otherwise I'll just open a ticket with org-mode maintainers.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any further suggestions. I tried replacing `org-backward-sentence` with `org-table-beginning-of-field` that the first function is calling, but I got an error `progn: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`. That does not make much sense to me,either.

Comment: Are you sure you are running 9.1.4.? Depending how you upgraded, you might have to run `org-reload` first.

Comment: Further experimentation showed that `(org-backward-sentence)` can be replaced by `(call-interactively 'org-table-beginning-of-field)`. I have changed the function code above. Does this work for you?

Comment: It turns out that the functions from `org-table.el` were not correctly read. I added `(load-file "/usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/org-table.elc")` to my init file and now everything works (I first unrolled back to 9.1.9 because I don't need the latest features).

Comment: I still don't understand why I need to manually load the `org-table.elc` file though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85634/discussion-between-raul-laasner-and-heikki).

Answer (score 0):

Following advice from @manandearth, I modified the `org-table-move-cell` function from `org-table.el` by commenting out a few lines:

```
(defun org-table-move-cell (&optional left)
  "Move the current cell to the right.  With arg LEFT, move to the left."
  (interactive "P")
  (unless (org-at-table-p) (user-error "Not at a table"))
  (org-table-find-dataline)
  (org-table-check-inside-data-field)
  (let* ((col (org-table-current-column))
         (col1 (if left (1- col) col))
         (colpos (if left (1- col) (1+ col)))
         (beg (org-table-begin))
         (end (copy-marker (org-table-end))))
    (when (and left (= col 1))
      (user-error "Cannot move cell further left"))
    (when (and (not left) (looking-at "[^|\n]*|[^|\n]*$"))
      (user-error "Cannot move cell further right"))
    (org-table-save-field
     ;; (goto-char beg)
     ;; (while (< (point) end)
     (unless (org-at-table-hline-p)
       (org-table-goto-column col1 t)
       (when (looking-at "|\\([^|\n]+\\)|\\([^|\n]+\\)|")
         (transpose-regions
          (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)
          (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2))
         )
       )
     ;; (forward-line)
     ;; )
     )
    (set-marker end nil)
    (org-table-goto-column colpos)
    (org-table-align)
    (when (or (not org-table-fix-formulas-confirm)
              (funcall org-table-fix-formulas-confirm "Fix formulas? "))
      (org-table-fix-formulas
       "$" (list (cons (number-to-string col) (number-to-string colpos))
                 (cons (number-to-string colpos) (number-to-string col))))
      (org-table-fix-formulas
       "$LR" (list (cons (number-to-string col) (number-to-string colpos))
                   (cons (number-to-string colpos) (number-to-string col))))
      )
    )
  )
```

The commented lines would otherwise have the effect of going to the beginning of table and then processing every line until the end of table is reached. Now only the current line is processed and thus only two cells are transposed.